# Removing a Mysql record

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a few thousand products in a mysql table for products.

Each product has a field for its manufacturer [manufacturer] stored as an integer - the manufacturer 'id'.

Over time some manufacturers have been deleted from the 'manufacturers' tables but the products have been left orphaned.

Is there a query I can run that will delete all orphaned products.

Something like

> 'Delete all products where products.manufacturer does not match
>   manufacturers.id'.

One further complication. A product can have more than one manufacturer so the products.manufacturer can have data like this **'1|75|432'** where 1, 75, 432 are each manufacturers.

Thanks

Comment: It would be a good idea to change your table design, if you can. Columns with character delimited lists produce most time a lot of trouble.

Comment: What if product has, lets say, 3 manufacturers, but only one of them has been deleted? Do you delete it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DELETE FROM product 
WHERE product_id not in (
    SELECT distinct p.product_id FROM Product p, manufacturer m 
    WHERE p.manufacturer REGEXP '[[:<:]]' + m.manufacturer_id + '[[:>:]]'
);
```

PS: This will remove only those record, for which all the manufacturer in the list are deleted

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in combination with [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
DELETE
    p
FROM
    products p
LEFT JOIN
    manufacturer m
ON
    FIND_IN_SET(m.id, REPLACE(p.manufacturer, '|', ','))
WHERE
    m.id IS NULL
```

**Explanation:**

You've got to replace your limiter `|` with the only one that FIND_IN_SET works with, the comma `,` first. If there's no matching manufacturer in the manufacturers table, then the value of the id column of your manufacturers table) will be NULL.

see [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) syntax:

> The preceding examples use INNER JOIN, but multiple-table DELETE
>   statements can use other types of join permitted in SELECT statements,
>   such as LEFT JOIN. For example, to delete rows that exist in t1 that
>   have no match in t2, use a LEFT JOIN:
>
> DELETE t1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;

see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af8dd9/5) for the SELECT statement.

**Note**

As I said in my comment, it would be better to change the database design. A product can have several manufacturers and a manufacturer can produce many products, the classical case for a [junction table](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/junction-table/info).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of preliminary things you should do:

> 1) Change the table design, tab limited multiple values is not a good
>   idea, in-fact in a situation where you have to join with its value.
>
> Sol: change the manufacturer_id to accommodate only a single value(FK
>   with manufacturer id table).
>
> 2) You need some scripts which'll insert multiple rows for different
>   tabbed values.
>
> Anyway you need this for remaining records.
>
> 3) Now we come to point we can join manufacturer and product tables.

You can now do left join products upon manufacturer to do other tasks efficiently.